# I want to contribute my own codes

Tags: python

I  want to contribute my own codes to the blender community. How do I do this? Can somebody help me out?

Comment: If you just want to share scripts or addons then the [Blender Artists forum](https://blenderartists.org/forum/) is the right place.If you want to become an official developer than [contact the developers through the official mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers).

From what I have seen you shoud start by getting Blender to compile on your prefered plafrom, and then browse the official Bugtracker for open any [bug reports](https://developer.blender.org/) and try to fix any by submitting a patch, so you prove your skills and intents and can get commit rights.

Answer (score 1):

If you want develop python addons, build one and advertise it on forums such as https://blenderartists.org/forum/ (there are probably many other good places as well, this is just what I use). Make sure you include good documentation on what it does and how to use it, or people are less likely to try it. If you want to sell it, https://blendermarket.com/ provides this option.

If you want to contribute to the main development of blender, you should read through https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Contents first. After that, you can discuss things on the developer mailing list or on IRC (see https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact for more details) and submit patches at https://developer.blender.org/